# how to set a default "save as" path for an existing file in ms office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any way , by which automatically a choosen file location opens when I click "Save As" instead of the earlier location , where the older file is saved.

I have a list pre filled invoices  in a folder ,  I want a  specific folder should automatically open when I click Save As (after editing it) , instead of same previous folder , is it possible  by any means ?

Answer (score 1):

The default save path should be located in the settings for the Office 2010 application you're using:

- **File** > *Options* > **Save** > *Default save location* > **OK**

  - If wanting to work in multiple folders one after the other, I'm not aware of a different way

Comment: I know that , but I am asking for a default "Save As" path.

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL  That should also set the default "Save As" path.  Does it not do so?  _(If not, I'll do some research and edit the answer)_

Comment: It does only for new files  (which are never saved before) ,but my question is regarding  old files

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL My bad, I misunderstood what you were asking.  I'll do some research and update the answer accordingly

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL Try the following (reference [4th post down](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/f80e7380-3793-4e21-bfc0-d370f2dc6faf/office-2016-default-quotsave-asquot-location?forum=Office2016ITPro)): `Reg ADD "HKCU\software\policies\microsoft\office\14.0\common\open find\restrictedbrowse" /v <Location> /t REG_SZ /d <Path> /f` (Edit accordingly: _`<Location>`_ to _Location Name_ and _`<Path>`_ to _Location Path_ - if either has whitespaces, use quotations and _don't_ include `<` or `>`)

Comment: Ok , I will try & revert

Comment: , I didn't found any relevant answers .

Comment: @RAHULJAISWAL Did that command work as, according to that post on the TechNet forum, it should